# Is it possible to change Microsoft Outlook web interface's settings so that opened emails from the unread email list are marked as read?

Tags: outlook.com

When I list unread emails in Microsoft Outlook web interface:

[image]

then open one of the unread emails, the email is still marked as unread.

Is it possible to change Microsoft Outlook web interface's settings so that opened emails are marked as read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Outlook's settings when viewing using Filters. However, you can work around it by manually marking the email as read when you have it open.
To do so,

1. click the ellipsis icon in the email actions shown above the message (when it's open)
   [image]
2. click the "mark as read" option from the dropdown menu.
   [image]

Now when you close the message and return to the filtered list view, it will no longer appear as "unread"